# Why does my div not show inline?

Tags: html, css

I want my `TOP 10` text to be placed the same level as `Kreuger National Park` but instead i get this[image]

```css
.info{
 background: url(pictures/info-shape.png) no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 950px;
}

.info-left{
 width: 50%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 38px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info-block{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
 font: 48pt "Lindsey", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #bd950c;
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

h3 {
 font: 28pt "Perpetua Titling MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 15px;
 display: inline;
}

p {
 text-align: justify;
 -moz-text-align-last: left;
 text-align-last: left;
}

.info-right{
 width: 30%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 100px;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-left">
    <h2 class="info-block">Kreuger</h2>
    <h3>National Park</h3>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United. States or China. The Nile River, which runs through 11 different countries in Africa, is the longest in the world.</p>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info-right">
    <h2 class="info-block">
      TOP 10
    </h2>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default vertical alignment for inline elements is `baseline`, so set it to what you're after, `top`:

```
.info-right {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```css
.info{
 background: url(pictures/info-shape.png) no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 950px;
}

.info-left{
 width: 50%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 38px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info-block{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
 font: 48pt "Lindsey", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #bd950c;
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

h3 {
 font: 28pt "Perpetua Titling MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 15px;
 display: inline;
}

p {
 text-align: justify;
 -moz-text-align-last: left;
 text-align-last: left;
}

.info-right{
 width: 30%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 100px;
 display: inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-left">
    <h2 class="info-block">Kreuger</h2>
    <h3>National Park</h3>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United. States or China. The Nile River, which runs through 11 different countries in Africa, is the longest in the world.</p>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info-right">
    <h2 class="info-block">
      TOP 10
    </h2>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When displaying divs as inline-blocks, you'll need to set the `vertical-align: top;` on you `.info-right` div.

```css
.info{
 background: url(pictures/info-shape.png) no-repeat;
 width: 100%;
 height: 950px;
}

.info-left{
 width: 50%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 38px;
 display: inline-block;
}

.info-block{
 margin-bottom: 30px;
}

h2 {
 font: 48pt "Lindsey", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #bd950c;
 display: inline;
 margin-right: 15px;
}

h3 {
 font: 28pt "Perpetua Titling MT", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: black;
 margin-left: 15px;
 display: inline;
}

p {
 text-align: justify;
 -moz-text-align-last: left;
 text-align-last: left;
}

.info-right{
 width: 30%;
 padding: 282px 0 0 100px;
 display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <div class="info-left">
    <h2 class="info-block">Kreuger</h2>
    <h3>National Park</h3>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United. States or China. The Nile River, which runs through 11 different countries in Africa, is the longest in the world.</p>
    <p class="info-block">Africa is comprised of desert, tropical, savanna grasslands, jungle and even subarctic climates. The top half of the continent is comprised of desert, and the Sahara Desert, the world’s hottest desert, is located in Northern Africa, and at 3.5 million square miles is approximately the size of the United.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="info-right">
    <h2 class="info-block">
      TOP 10
    </h2>
  </div> 
</div>
```